# ERROR Could not update index entry. Action: 'Saved'

Tags: asp.net, lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

We've just taken over a site based in Sitecore and the log file has this occurring every 1 - 5 mins throughout the day.

Anyone seen anything like this before and know what the cause and solution could be? The site also suffers from a slowdown issue on 1 page load occurring ever few mins which could be related.

> ManagedPoolThread #7 10:10:41 INFO  Starting update of index for the
>   database 'master' (1 pending). ManagedPoolThread #7 10:10:41 ERROR
>   Could not update index entry. Action: 'Saved', Item:
>   '{0D80F9BA-5BBB-4A43-8B87-63E7A0F9A484}' Exception:
>   System.IO.IOException Message: read past EOF Source: Lucene.Net    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.Refill()    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadByte()    at
>   Lucene.Net.Store.IndexInput.ReadInt()    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.Read(Directory directory, String
>   segmentFileName)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.IndexFileDeleter..ctor(Directory directory,
>   IndexDeletionPolicy policy, SegmentInfos segmentInfos, TextWriter
>   infoStream, DocumentsWriter docWriter)    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryIndexReader.DoCommit()    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Commit()    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.DecRef()    at
>   Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Close()    at
>   Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.DeleteItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.UpdateItem(Item item)    at
>   Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.Provider_OnUpdateItem(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateItem(HistoryEntry entry,
>   Database database)    at
>   Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateIndex(HistoryEntry
>   entry, Database database)
>
> ManagedPoolThread #7 10:10:41 INFO  Update of index for the database
>   'master' done.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a corrupt index to me. My first choice would be to do a full "rebuild indexes" on the server where these logs are being generated. Started from Sitecore Control Panel -> Databases.

Comment: We have a very similar issue - this is the strategy we're using, but in some cases the rebuilt index immediately corrupts again and the same issue persists. Doesn't happen all the time though.

Comment: My local 7.5 just started doing the same thing. Rebuild indexes didn't help. What did help is removing the index files from the file system completely (had to `iisreset` as stopping that particular site still kept a lock on some files by IIS processes) and then rebuilding the indexes